# When I ran a backup using Cassy, but there is no response

Tags: cassy

I'm running a backup job using Cassy for Cassandra nodes, but the results of running the grpcurl command are not returning.

### Environment

Cloud Service : AWS
Number of cassandra nodes : 6

### Backup Command

```
grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"cluster_id": "ScalarDL-aaaa-bbbb-cccc", "backup_type": 1}' cassy-1.prd.ddi-dlt.internal:20051 rpc.Cassy.TakeBackup
```

### List backups statues

When I run the ListBackup, it looks like the following

```
grpcurl -plaintext -d '{"limit": 6, "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-aaaa-bbbb-cccc"}' cassy-1.prd.ddi-dlt.internal:20051  rpc.Cassy.ListBackups
```

```json
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
      "target_ip": "10.10.2.1",
      "snapshot_id": "1234-5678-90ab",
      "created_at": "1605072056752",
      "updated_at": "1605072056763",
      "backup_type": 1,
      "status": "INITIALIZED"
    },
    {
      "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
      "target_ip": "10.10.2.2",
      "snapshot_id": "1234-5678-90ab",
      "created_at": "1605072056752",
      "updated_at": "1605072056767",
      "backup_type": 1,
      "status": "INITIALIZED"
    },
    {
      "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
      "target_ip": "10.10.2.3",
      "snapshot_id": "1234-5678-90ab",
      "created_at": "1605072056752",
      "updated_at": "1605072056752",
      "backup_type": 1,
      "status": "INITIALIZED"
    },
    {
      "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
      "target_ip": "10.10.2.4",
      "snapshot_id": "1234-5678-90ab",
      "created_at": "1605072056752",
      "updated_at": "1605072056775",
      "backup_type": 1,
      "status": "INITIALIZED"
    },
    {
      "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
      "target_ip": "10.10.2.5",
      "snapshot_id": "1234-5678-90ab",
      "created_at": "1605072056752",
      "updated_at": "1605072056756",
      "backup_type": 1,
      "status": "INITIALIZED"
    },
    {
      "cluster_id": "ScalarDL-aaaa-bbbb-cccc",
      "target_ip": "10.10.2.6",
      "snapshot_id": "1234-5678-90ab",
      "created_at": "1605072056752",
      "updated_at": "1605072056779",
      "backup_type": 1,
      "status": "INITIALIZED"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

backup_type:1 is a cluster-wide backup that requires the SRV record of an application.
Do you properly register an SRV record?